# Safe struct array as plain byte stream

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have given an array of structs:

```
typedef struct sRawMsg{
    int a;
}sRawMsg;

sRawMsg RawMsg[10];
```

First the struct array entries are filled with data. Then the data is copied to an output buffer given as a 2D array.

```
// sending buffer which allocates memory for the array struct
static unsigned char sendingBuffer[10][sizeof(sRawMsg)];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    sRawMsg* pMsg = &(RawMsg[i]);
    // data is now stored in the struct array @ pos i
    ...
    // data from the struct entry is now saved in the output sending buffer 
    memcopy(&(sendingBuffer[i][0]), pMsg, sizeof(sRawMsg));
}
```

The obtained output buffer is transmitted as an plain byte array over an wireless connection. Since I am new to C programming I want to ask whether a more efficient / elegant / secure way exist to handle the struct array data.

Comment: Apart from the misspelled `memcpy()`, this looks alright. You could leave out some of the parentheses and shorten (beautify) the code though.

Comment: You are looking for "serialization". Don't just write internal data structures, this is a good way to trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have any padding in the structure (one element structures don't have padding with any normal compiler), you could simply pass the

```
(unsigned char *)&RawMsg[0]
```

as the argument to your sending function.

If you were converting the data to a fixed format (e.g. network order), or if your structure included a mixture of types with padding between the elements, or if your structure included pointers to strings (or other pointers to data), you'd have to work harder — use serialization analogous to what you are doing.  With pointers to strings, you'd probably need a protocol that knows how to identify the lengths of strings.  One such convention is known as TLV ([Type, length, value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value)). Another (vastly more complex) one is [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One).  Or you can use a format such as [JSON](http://json.org/) or [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/), or maybe Google's [Protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: Not sure, but I think there might very well be padding at the end e.g. to enforce a specific alignment. And that is less a matter of the compiler than the ABI. And the standard very well allows it.

Comment: @Olaf: Go experiment — come back when you find a structure that has one element that also has padding.  Bit fields don't count.  By definition, an array of type T is laid out consecutively with no padding between.  If you have a `struct U { T t; };`, then it only needs the same space and alignment as type T, so an array of U normally consists of consecutive elements with no padding needed.  A compiler _could_ add padding, but compiler writers _don't_ let their compilers add padding unnecessarily.

Comment: Experimenting is a bad advice in C; there could very well be a broken compiler.I did not question that "an array of type T is laid out consecutively with no padding between". But here `T` is the `struct`, not whatever it contains. I do agree this might be more theoretical, but it is useless to rely on it. In general this kind of serialisation is a bad idea. Instead element-wise serialisation to a well defined transmission (or storage) format should be used. Not necessarily a character format or with named entries.